# node - How to remove x number of letters from a word

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

As an exercise I'm trying to create a simple guess the letter games. I've writed this code that will extract a random word from a `.txt` dictionary file.

```js
    fs.readFile(filename, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (error, data) => {
        if( error ) return new Error(error);
        let randomWord;
        const d = data.split('\n');
        for(let i = d.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
            const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            const tmp = d[i];
            d[i] = d[r];
            d[r] = tmp;
            randomWord = d[r];
        }
    
        const splittedWord = randomWord.split('');
        //console.log(splittedWord);
        
        console.log(`Selected word length is ${splittedWord.length}`);
        const mid = Math.floor( splittedWord.length / 2 ); 

        //console.log(mid);
        
        let outputWord;

        for(let e = mid - 1; e > 0; e--){
            const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (e + 1));
            outputWord = splittedWord.splice(r, 1, '_');
        }
        // the output word have letters removed but sometimes not in a random way 
        console.log(splittedWord.toString());
        
            
    });
```

To randomize the extraction of the word to use, I've implemented the [Fisher-Yates algo](https://dev.to/codebubb/how-to-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript-2ikj). I'm able to get a random word from the text file and I'm splitting it to get the an array that will contain the single chars of the word. What I want to achive is to remove an x number of letters from the word before display it to the user that will need to guess the removed letters to recreate the original word. What's the best way to achive this? I was thinking to use the same algo that is randomize the word extraction but not sure about. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I have made a change in `for` loop

```
let x = 3 // your expected x
let newString=""
for (let i = 3; i < splittedWord.length; i++) {
   newString=newString + splittedWord[i]
}
console.log(newString) // after removing x number of letters
```

add this code in place of for loop

Comment: In this way the number of letters is hardcoded, isn't any way to have a more random number? Please see the question update

Answer (score -1):

```
let currentTimestamp=Date.now().toString()
currentTimestamp = currentTimestamp.split("")
let singleDigitRand = currentTimestamp[12]
console.log(singleDigitRand)
```

You can select x like this

Comment: why are you using a timestamp?

Comment: To generate random number